Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
I upgraded Android Studio to Iguana recently and it broke my project.  I can't sync Gradle and it gives me the following error.
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.3.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

My build files:
**build.gradle.kts (Project) **
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.3.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.3.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}

**build.gradle.kts (:app) **
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        signingConfigs {
            create("release") {
                storeFile = file("/raw/keystore.jks")
                storePassword = "password"
                keyAlias = "key0"
                keyPassword = "password"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            getByName("release") {
                signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isDebuggable = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}


**settings.gradle.kts **
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "My App"
include(":app")


It's a super simple project structure but here's the folder just in case
enter image description here

I've looked at other similar posts.

I'm not using a proxy.
I'm not in offline mode.
I'm able to download other versions of Gradle
API is 34. Java v17.  AGP v8.4.
I've tried Gradle v8.1 - 8.7. Gradle JDK 17
Tried Gradle Wrapper and local versions. Tried all the Gradle JDK variations.
Tried swapping around plugin repositories
Tried invalidating the caches. Deleting ~/.gradle and project .gradle folders
Reinstalling Android studio, restart Windows, restarting computer
Reset default settings
Opened a new empty Android project and got the same error!

What am I missing?

Have you tried running gradle commands from the command line? Strange that your error message has a different plugin version to your build file

I hadn't tried running gradle from command line. I ran grandlew test and discovered Java_HOME wasn't in my Environment variables! So I added the same JDK I'm using to my system variables. Ran ./gradlew tasks and got the same plugin error.  (I went around a made sure I'm aligned all the Gradle versions accurately too.)

You could try adding maven { setUrl("https://maven.google.com") } to pluginManagement.repositories {}
